# Wordpress media-uploader save to a specific location

Tags: wordpress, configuration, media, uploader

I'm trying to implement a plugin allowing to download an image and save it to a specific location (relative to my plugin path - ie plugins/my_plugin/img) rather than in the default WP location.

I'd like to use the media uploader - but I've not found any way to define/change where media are uploaded.

Is it possible to customize the download path? and if yes, how can it be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the upload folder via the Settings --> Media or adding the following line in the wp-config.php:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

Comment: Hello this isn’t a solution to the problem as it will globally change the upload directory. I only want to store the media uploaded using the plugin in a specific location.